# Show that there exists a unique $z_0\in B(0,1)$ s.t $f(z_0)=z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, maximum-principle, fixed-points, rouches-theorem

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and let $f:B(0,1+\varepsilon )\rightarrow B(0,1)$ be a holomorphic function. Show that there exists a unique $z_0\in B(0,1)$ s.t $f(z_0)=z_0$.

For this problem, I don't want to use the Earle-Hamilton fixed-point Theorem because my complex-analysis textbook doesn't have it, which implies the uniqueness of $z_0$ straightforwardly.

However, what I'm considering instead is the maximum modulus principle (or Schwarz Lemma or Rouche's Theorem).

Here's my idea.

> Since $B(0,1)$ is bounded, $\exists \alpha \in B(0,1+\varepsilon )$ s.t $|f(z)| \leq |f(\alpha)| <1$ for any $z \in B(0,1+\varepsilon )$.
>
> Then, by the Maximum modulus principle, $f$ is constant.
>
> So, $f(z)=z_0$ for any $z\in B(0,1+\varepsilon )$ and for some $z_0 \in B(0,1)$.
>
> Since, $z_0 \in B(0,1) \subset B(0,1\varepsilon )$, $f(z_0)=z_0$.
>
> Lastly, the uniqueness of $z_0$ is obvious because for any $z \in B(0,1) \setminus \{z_0\}$, $z \neq z_0$. $\blacksquare $

How does this sound like?

I have a little doubt due to the fact that $f$ is constant.

Another question is this. If we want to use the Schwarz Lemma for this problem, then we would need the condition $f(0)=0$. But, since $f$ might not satisfy this, I wonder how we should modify this Lemma?
I think we can let $g(z)=f(z)-f(0)$ so that the Lemma can be used. Would this method work?

Update:

I'm also trying to use Rouche's Theorem, comparing $f(z)$ and $g(z)=z$ on $\partial B(0,1)$.

But, I am stuck at showing $|f(z_0)-z_0| \neq |f(z_0)|+1$ for any $z_0 \in \partial B(0,1)$. How this could be shown?

Update:

I finally could get a simple solution to this problem using Rouche's Theorem.

> Note that $\overline{B(0,1)}\subseteq B(0,1+\varepsilon )$.
>
> Now, we are going to compare $|f(z)|$ and $|-z|$ on $\partial B(0,1)$.
>
> As $f(z) \in B(0,1)$, $|f(z)|<1$ for any $z \in \partial B(0,1)$. Also, $|-z|=1$ for any $z \in \partial B(0,1)$.
>
> So, $|f(z)|<|-z|$ on $\partial B(0,1)$.
>
> By a Corollary derived from Rouche's Theorem, we can say that $-z$ and $f(z)-z$ have the same number of zeros in $B(0,1)$.
>
> Then, this implies that $f(z)-z = 0$ at a unique $z_0 \in B(0,1)$.
>
> Hence, we conclude that there exists unique $z_0 \in B(0,1)$ such that $f(z_0)=z_0$.

However, I still want to know if it is possible to use Schwarz Lemma for this problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is incorrect as $z/2$ for example works for any $\epsilon<1$ etc; unicity follows from Schwartz pick immediately, for existence I would look at iterates and use montel

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your answer. However, my textbook doesn't cover the Schwarz-Pick Lemma as well, but only covers Schwarz Lemma. But, it looks like Schwarz-Pick Lemma follows from Schwarz Lemma, so I wonder how do we show that f(0)=0 to use the Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: I have proven the Brouwer's fixed point theorem. I would advise you to transform the ball into a rectangular prism first. This might make it easier.

Comment: Have you taken Topology?

Comment: @Wakem No, I haven't :(

Comment: @Wakem Do you think we can use the Rouche's Theorem for this problem instead?

Comment: The proof using Rouché's theorem is also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115402/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/707879/42969